# Como se harían estas funciones de forma asíncrona para que se ejecute la sentencia sql

Tags: php, javascript, sql

El siguiente código cumple su función de actualizar la columna en la base de datos pero la alerta definidia al final no se muestra, otro problema que hay es que no puedo activar y desactivar indefinidas veces sin recargar la pagina, es decir, si activo, desactivo y vuelvo a activar se queda desactivado porque solo me permite una ejecución  por carga de la pagina.

Código:

```
   <?php
      function Activar(){
        echo "¡Su bolsa de trabajo ha sido activada!";
      }
      
      function Desactivar(){
        echo "¡Su bolsa de trabajo ha sido desactivada!";
      }
    ?>
    
    <script>
          function funcionActivar(){
              setTimeOutAct(function (){
                <?php 
                  $sql="
                    UPDATE usuario SET Trabajo='Activada' WHERE Correo='" . $conexion->real_escape_string($mail) ."'";
                    $result=$conexion->query($sql);           
                ?>        
              });
              alert('<?php echo Activar(); ?>') 
          }
      </script>
<script>
      function funcionDesactivar(){
          setTimeOutDes(function (){
            <?php 
              $sql="
                UPDATE usuario SET Trabajo='Desactivada' WHERE Correo_user='" . $conexion->real_escape_string($mail) ."'";
                $result=$conexion->query($sql);           
            ?>        
          });
        alert('<?php echo Desactivar(); ?>');
      }
  </script>
```

Comment: Justo para eso tienes las funciones asíncronas de JS :) Échales un vistazo, completa tu código y, si no te sale, amplía la pregunta con lo que has intentado y el error que obtienes y continuamos ayudándote. ¡Ánimo que casi lo tienes!

Comment: Aunque, si lo único que quieres es mostrar u ocultar una columna de la tabla, con un simple `display:none;`, también lo solucionas... ¿Podrías mostrar el código de la tabla que quieres 'activar/desactivar'?

Comment: No es mostrar es actualizar, tengo que hacer un update y actualizar un campo de la tabla

Comment: Entonces sí: funciones asíncronas o AJAX. Ten en cuenta que tienes que hacerte una pequeña API en PHP que reciba las peticiones que lances desde JS

Comment: Pues no me salgo con la mia

Comment: Oye, buen intento... ojalá fuera tan fácil. A ver si el fin de semana saco un rato y te preparo un ejemplo básico para que veas cómo va, ¡y sin AJAX!

Comment: vale, esperaré tu respuesta

Comment: Las query's son distintas, seguramente por eso no te guarda los cambios que dices

Comment: Asincronia? donde quires aplicarla?

Comment: tengo un botón con una función OnClick(funcionActivar()), lo que busco es que al presionar el botón muestre una alerta y ejecute una sentencia sql. pero solo me hace uno de los dos.

Comment: No lo veo en el codigo, pero si quieres asincronia, tendras que usar, por ejemplo una llamada AJAX

Comment: podrias publicar una respuesta con una posible solución, no se utilizar ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para hacerlo existen muchas maneras, pero viendo que no dominas el tema AJAX y para no complicarlo lo haremos todo en ficheros separados. No es la forma mas eficiente.

Igualmente te dejare un ejemplo con un controlador, que en este caso si seria la mejor forma.

### Empezamos con la versión mas sencilla

(con ficheros separados)

Para este caso necesitas 3 ficheros.

1º Un index.html, el encargado de mostrar los botones cara al usuario.

2º Un php, activa.php, que se encargara de activar el contenido.

3º Un php, desactiva.php, que se encargara de desactivar el contenido.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>SO</title>
    <!-- JQUERY -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="funcionActivar()">Activar!</button>
    <button onclick="funcionDesactivar()">Desactivar!</button>
</body>
</html>
<script>
    function funcionActivar(){
           $.ajax({
                url: 'activa.php',
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                }
           });
      }

     function funcionDeasactivar(){
           $.ajax({
                url: 'desactiva.php',
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                }
           });
      }
</script>
```

---

**activa.php**

```
<?php

//Establecemos conexion, ya sea con PDO o como lo hagas tu.
$link = new mysqli("192.168.1.1", "srsole", "my_pass", "module_cli");
$link->set_charset("utf8") or die();
$consulta = "UPDATE usuario SET Trabajo='Activada' WHERE Correo='" . $mail ."';"; //Desconozco de donde sacas $mail, asi que lo pongo tal cual.
$result = mysqli_query($link, $consulta);
echo "Activado con exito!";
?>
```

---

**desactiva.php**

```
<?php

//Establecemos conexion, ya sea con PDO o como lo hagas tu.
$link = new mysqli("192.168.1.1", "srsole", "my_pass", "module_cli");
$link->set_charset("utf8") or die();
$consulta = "UPDATE usuario SET Trabajo='Desactivada' WHERE Correo='" . $mail ."';"; //Desconozco de donde sacas $mail, asi que lo pongo tal cual.
$result = mysqli_query($link, $consulta);
echo "Desactivado con exito!";
?>
```

---

---

### Version con contralodor

En este caso solo necestiamos 2 ficheros:

1º index.html, el encargado de mostrar los botones cara al usuario.

2º controller.php, que se encargara de activar/desactivar el contenido segun el parametro enviado (POST).

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>SO</title>
    <!-- JQUERY -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="toggleActivar(1)">Activar!</button>
    <button onclick="toggleActivar(0)">Desactivar!</button>
</body>
</html>
<script>
    function toggleActivar(x){
           $.ajax({
                url: 'controller.php',
                data: {"activo": x},
                type: "POST",
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                }
           });
      }
</script>
```

---

**controller.php**

```
<?php
//Recibimos los datos por POST
$activo = $_POST["activo"]; //esto valdra 1 ó 0
//Establecemos conexion, ya sea con PDO o como lo hagas tu.
$link = new mysqli("192.168.1.1", "srsole", "my_pass", "module_cli"); 
$link->set_charset("utf8") or die();
if(intval($activo) == 1){
    $consulta = "UPDATE usuario SET Trabajo='Activada' WHERE Correo='" . $mail ."';"; //Desconozco de donde sacas $mail, asi que lo pongo tal cual.

    $x = "Activado con exito";
}else{
    $consulta = "UPDATE usuario SET Trabajo='Desactivada' WHERE Correo='" . $mail ."';"; //Desconozco de donde sacas $mail, asi que lo pongo tal cual.

    $x = "Desactivado con exito";
}
$result = mysqli_query($link, $consulta);
echo $x;
?>
```

---

No es exactamente un controlador, pero es mas eficiente.

Comment: Viéndolo hecho parece fácil, espero la versión con controlador.